# Python gql TypeError: Not an AST Node:

Tags: python-3.x, graphql, typeerror, gql

This query works when I am querying the database directly but when I use python gql, I keep getting this error. I can not find how to stop getting that error anywhere.

```
query = f"""query{{
   addresses(line1: "{street}", city: "{city}", zip: "{zip}", subdivision: {state}){{
     entities{{
       id
     }}
   }}
 }}"""

GraphQL = sonar.execute(query=query, variable_values=None)

Output: TypeError: Not an AST Node: 'query{\n  addresses(line1:............
```

Comment: variables should be used, not fn in fn/string manipulations, it's graphql abusing

Comment: @xadm Wym "variables"? where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't wrap the query in `gql()` the above should look like:

```py
gql(
"""query{{
   addresses(line1: "{street}", city: "{city}", zip: "{zip}", subdivision: {state}){{
     entities{{
       id
     }}
   }}
 }}""".format(...)
)
```

Comment: haha I just did the same thing and saw your post

Comment: Sometimes those are the worst things to debug (;